# Function return type overloading C++

Tags: c++, overloading, return-type

i've read that you can only overload functions by argument type and not by return type.

Recently i tried to learn how to use the `<filesystem>`.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) i found that the `current_path();` function has a return type of `path`, but if you call it like this `current_path(path('path/to/a/directory'));` it changes your CWD and returns `void`

***QUESTIONS***

- is it possible to do that, or is it just the website that gives false information?
- if it is possible, how can i do it myself?
- i'm new in C++ so explain in a way a beginner can understand.

Comment: Note that the `path` and `void` returning variants have different argument types.

Comment: You are correct that functions can only be overloaded by arguments. `std::filesystem::current_path()` has 4 overloads, each with different arguments.  The overload that takes no arguments as input returns a `path`.  The 2 overloads that take a `path` as input both return a `void`. This is clearly shown in the doc you linked to.

Comment: You can't overload *only* on return type. Each overload must have different argument types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload based on return type alone. In a nutshell, the compiler figures out what overload to call based on the arguments. Hence, you cannot distinguish two overloads based *only* on return type:

```
int f() { return 42; }
double f() { return 3.14; }       // error redeclaration of f()

f();   // calls what function ?!?
```

When parameter types differ, two overloads can have different return types:

```
 int g() { return 42; }          // (1)
 double g(int) { return 3.14; }  // (2)

 g();  // calls (1)
 g(1); // calls (2)
```

While vanilla overloading does not let you overload based only on the return type, there is a neat trick that can emulate it. Bear with me.

The above `f` overloads cause a compiler error, because they arent a valid overload set (differ only by return type). But we can define two seperate functions:

```
int f_int(){ return 42; }    
double f_double() { return 3.14; }
```

We can define a type whose purpose is nothing but to be convertible to either an `int` or a `double`. During that conversion we can call the respective `f_x`:

```
struct foo {
    operator int() { return f_int(); }
    operator double() { return f_double(); }
};
```

Now these two lines:

```
int x = foo{};
double y = foo{};
```

call `f_int` or `f_double`, respectively, based on what we assign it too.

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EG77b7b9f)

However, take this with a grain of salt. It is rare that you actually need to overload based on return type only. Those two lines can be rather obscure when it isnt clear from context what is happening. Implicit conversions are always a source of confusion. Last but least, it also doesn't go well with "almost always auto".

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to do that

Yes, it is possible. Different overloads can have different return types.

Return types can also be the same between different overloads, but the parameter list cannot be the same between different overloads.

> or is it just the website that gives false information?

The linked documentation is correct.

> if it is possible, how can i do it myself?

Same way as the standard overloaded functions in question. Here is a minimal example:

```
int foo();     // 1
void foo(int); // 2

int i = foo(); // calls 1
foo(i);        // calls 2

void foo(); // NOT OK
            // same parameter list as 1
            // but different return type
```